# Svelte importing svg as compoment works weird

Tags: html, css, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I've created this [repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/0ec12cb8ec8540db8abd89619728c694?version=3.50.1) to demonstrate this issue. One SVG is just added inline and works ok, the other is imported as a component and doesn't work as intended. What's the difference? How do I get this scenario to work?

Comment: Questions should be self contained; please include all relevant code *in* the question, not just in an off-site link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the style scoping. Since the SVG is inside another component, the styles of the parent component do not apply, you need to use `:global` or work with CSS variables:

```css
  .my-stuff-svg-container :global(svg) {
    color: white;
    height: 1rem;
    width: 1rem;
    transition: 0.25s ease;
  }
```

Comment: Hah! thx! That was a fast answer

Answer (score 1):

Basically yes, you missed the styling approach.
Your both SVG is working fine except,

I found that both are using same `id` that's why background overlapping, you can try with changing that.